# angular, Java : HTTP request not going to server, while URL is valid

Tags: java, angular, angular-formly

I am working in an application : Java Backend  and Angular frontend. I am using angular Fromly, data is coming to service, but from the service it is not going to server.

lets share the code snipts:

**Service Code:**

```
    export class RecommendationRequestService {
        readonly ROOT_URL = environment.apiUrl + '/am/v1/recommendation-requests';
    
        constructor(private http: HttpClient, private configService: RecommenderConfigService) {
        } ​
   ​
       ​updateData(interviewStatus: InterviewStatusRecommendation): Observable<any> {
           ​console.log(interviewStatus);
           ​return this.http.put<any>(this.ROOT_URL, interviewStatus);
       ​}
   ​}
```

This line is printing intended data set : `console.log(interviewStatus);`
The server is running.

The code from where the service is being called :

```
onSubmit() {
    this.model.recommendationRequest.agentInitiationId = this.agentInitiationId;
    const subs = this.service.updateData(this.model).subscribe(response => {
            console.log('------' + response);
            if (response === 'OK') {
                this.notify.success('Request Recommendation Update success.');
            } else {
                this.notify.error('Request Recommendation Update fail.');
            }
        },
        err => {
            if (err.error.hasOwnProperty('code') && err.error.code === 1000) {
                this.notify.error(CommonEnum.VALIDATION_ERROR);
            }
        });
    subs.unsubscribe();
}
```

`console.log('------' + response);` this line should print at least `-----`, But nothing.

I have checked the network monitor from the browser, no call is going.

What might be the possible issue, any thing from `fromly`?

Comment: Did you check the console? Any errors there?

Comment: Assuming other requests do reach your server, I'd probably try removing `subs.unsubscribe()` first. It's just a hunch really, but I feel like immediately unsubscribing inside the calling method isn't correct.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it incorrect as Aldin Bradaric also updated in the comment, as soon as you make the call on the very next moment you are unsubscribing it. This is what you should do :

```
public subs: [] = [];
onSubmit() {
    this.model.recommendationRequest.agentInitiationId = this.agentInitiationId;
    const subs = this.service.updateData(this.model).subscribe(response => {
            console.log('------' + response);
            if (response === 'OK') {
                this.notify.success('Request Recommendation Update success.');
            } else {
                this.notify.error('Request Recommendation Update fail.');
            }
        },
        err => {
            if (err.error.hasOwnProperty('code') && err.error.code === 1000) {
                this.notify.error(CommonEnum.VALIDATION_ERROR);
            }
        });
    //subs.unsubscribe();   // remove it and add it to the lifecycle hooks
    this.subs.push(subs);

}
```

```
ngOnDestroy() {
     // create an array of subscription
     this.subs.forEach(sub => sub.unsubscribe() )
}
```